# Facebook Graph api doesn't return everything

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just found out that Facebook updated their graph api and now require an access token to retrieve like counts for a page to be displayed on an external website. I went through the motions of setting up an app to get the token and have the following:

```
    $fbData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/myFacebookName?access_toke=MyAppId|MySecretToken'));
                print_r($fbData);
```

It seems to only be returning objects:

```
 stdClass Object ( [name] => My Facebook Name [id] => id number )
```

And that is all, giving me nothing to parse through. The name and id coming through are correct so there is a connection happening. Note that I have edited out some information so MyFacebookName and MyAppId|MySecretToken are actually populated with the correct info.  Any ideas how to get the full JSON list to grab page likes? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Tobi and further reading the graph api, documentation I was able to get the number of likes with with following:

```
$fbData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/name?fields=likes&access_token=appId|accessToken'));
<?php echo number_format($fbData->likes);?>
```

Comment: _“Am I missing something?”_ – yes, that there _is_ a changelog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically request the fields you want in the response. In your case this would be

```
https://graph.facebook.com/myFacebookName?fields=id,name,likes&access_toke=MyAppId|MySecretToken
```

I don't understand why you say there "nothing to parse", because the object *IS* returned and can be used. So what's the problem?

Using `echo $fbData['likes']` should give you the number of likes.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading